# Excel how to group up data by percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a graph which many Series, but I only need the first 5 and I want to group up the rest as a Series of its own called "others".

Here you can see how all the smaller data below the top 6 agglomerate with each other.

[image: table]

On the Pivot table I tried by selecting the smaller data and using the "group" option, but when using that option it is not grouped the way I want, some of the columns were duplicated in both groups. I also tried to use the "Value Filters" option and group in top 5, but that way only eliminates the other series.

This is my pivot table, and the data I want to group all the columns outside the top 5 ex. (Faroe Islands to Ireland):

[image: pivot]

This is the result of when IM trying to group selecting the data outside of the top 5 (Faroe Islands to Ireland) and using the "group" option:

[image: result]

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1770712/edit) your question and explain 1) how you've tried to solve the issue and 2) what result do you get. Please add all relevant formulas enclosed in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting. Please don't add new info or answer questions in comments.

Comment: @Camilo Enriquez ,,,, it's simple either separate Top 5 Values using FILTER command or any as a dataset then make a graph ,,, and second graph with rest of the data. Means U have to make 2 graph. OR use a LOGICAL FILTER formula based on cell value and make ONE DATA Set which filter once TOP 5 nxt other,, and make a chart,,, will be dynamic based on cell value & filtered Records !!